# Issue with subscriptions on multiple instances of a template

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

Here is the scenario. I have a template that contains a #each loop and renders an instance of a particular template, setting the data context on each template as per the docs.

```
<template name = 'live'>
<div class = 'row'>
    {{#each runways}}
        <div class = 'col-md-2'>
            {{> runway_panel}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>

</template>
```

And this is the helper backing it:

```
Template.live.helpers({
    runways: function(){
        return Runway_Data.find();
    }
});
```

This works, my issue is as follows. Each live_event_log instance has a template level subscription that subscribes to a publication that takes the _id parameter of the data context, like so:

```
Template.runway_panel.onCreated(function(){
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function(){
        var subscription = instance.subscribe('runway_status', this.data._id);
    });

    instance.status = function(){
        return Runway_Status.find();
    }

});
```

This is the publication:

```
Meteor.publish('runway_status', function(runway){ 

    if(this.userId){
        //Retrieve the last know status for the given runway

        return Runway_Status.find({runway: runway});  
    }

});
```

This is when it all falls apart, I get this on the browser console:

```
 [Log] Exception in queued task: http://localhost:3000/client/views/live/runway_panel.js?4efaac87b39527d3dfd3d65a174520f9bce3c565:4:73 (meteor.js, line 888)_withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476:16
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1864:54
_withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2197:16
```

As soon as I comment out the subscription line everything else works, am I missing something really obvious here? Could it have something to do with multiple subscriptions to the same publication?

Thank you! :)

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Jeremy S. input and some sleep after a night shift i've finally figured it out without an autorun. So here it goes for posterity:

```
Template.runway_panel.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.subscribe('runway_status', this.data._id);
});
```

Should probably have tried getting some sleep before trying again!

Comment: can you give us the original console error? Not the log. It's possible that you might need to add a check if `if (this.data._id)`

Comment: I've already tried that but I get the same error, data._id definitely exists because if I print it to the log before subscribing it always exists.  It looks like it is something to do with blaze. I apologise for my ignorance but what do you mean by the original error? What I posted is all I'm getting on the console (Part of it at least, the log entry goes on forever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `this.data._id` in your subscription, which right now is scoped to the innermost function. You want `instance.data._id` (which is nonreactive so you wouldn't need an `autorun`) or `Template.currentData()` (which is reactive).

```
Template.runway_panel.onCreated(function(){
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function(){
        var data = Template.currentData();
        var subscription = instance.subscribe('runway_status', data._id);
    });
});
```

Also note that in your publication, you should mark it as `this.ready()` if `this.userId` is `undefined`. But that's not the source of the error.

Comment: Finally got it to work, thank you! You've got me intrigued now though. You say instance.data._id is nonreactive. How would you rewrite this using instance.data._id instead of an autorun? There are a few of days rendered at the same time and I'm trying to keep overhead to a minimum. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, never mind, figured it out and recorded it on the question. Thanks Jeremy S., greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, userId is a function and userId() would return current user id. And you could check [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) to learn more detail of `instance.subscribe`.

I think your problem may happen in getting `runway._id` in `Meteor.publish`

```js
Template.runway_panel.onCreated(function(){
  var instance = this;
  // instance subscribe data whose _id is runwayPanelId
  instance.autorun(function(){
    var dataContext = Template.currentData();
    var subscription = instance.subscribe('runway_status', dataContext.runwayPanelId);
  });

  instance.status = function(){
    return Runway_Status.find();
  }
});

// publication
Meteor.publish('runway_status', function(runway){ 
  // using Meteor.userId() to get current user id
  if(Meteor.userId()){
      //Retrieve the last know status for the given runway
      return Runway_Status.find({runway: runway});  
    }
});
```

---

```html
<template name = 'live'>
  <div class = 'row'>
    {{#each runways}}
      <div class = 'col-md-2'>
        {{> runway_panel runwayPanelId=_id}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: I was under the impression the Meteor.userId() was available anywhere BUT publish functions :/ It's not that anyway, I'm making some progress. I'm coming to the same kind of solution as you suggest there with dataContext. Still working away at it! Thank you