# Issue with multiple subscriptions on one publication

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a page that generates a series of post templates, each of which subscribes to a single publication. I'm running into an issue where passing the post ID to my publication does not return any results. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

I have tried using console.log() inside onCreated (both inside and outside of the autorun) to make sure that my IDs are correctly generated and have also tried other query values (such as {$exists:true}) to ensure that my query is working.

```
// client    
CommentSubs = new SubsManager();

Template.post.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.ready = new ReactiveVar();
    self.autorun(function() {
        var commentParent = this._id;
        var handle = CommentSubs.subscribe('comments', commentParent);
        self.ready.set(handle.ready());
    });
});


// server
Meteor.publish("comments", function (commentParent) {
    return Posts.find({commentParent: commentParent}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}});
});
```

I am new to meteor so perhaps I am missing something that should be obvious.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Try this way: `self.autorun(function () {
     if (handle.ready()) {
       self.ready.set(true);
     }
   }`

Comment: Wrapping the self.ready.set(true) inside if (handle.ready) doesn't seem to fix the issue. If that were the solution, I think that changing commentParent to {$exists:true} would not make the subscription work.

Comment: I solved this by using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690094/issue-with-subscriptions-on-multiple-instances-of-a-template?rq=1 as inspiration. I took everything out of the autorun except for the self.ready.set(handle.ready()) and now everything seems to be working correctly.